# How to hide header on MVC3 WebGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

Is there some easy way to hide header for MVC3 WebGrid extension? Something like

```
 var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canSort:false, canPage:false, showHeader:false);
```

I can probably set css style for header that will cause header not showing, though I'd rather have this done via code.

Thanks,

Antonin

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could pass it to the `GetHtml` method:

```
@grid.GetHtml(displayHeader: false)
```

For additional options you may take a look at the [following blog post](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/154/Looking-At-The-WebMatrix-WebGrid).

Comment: how to make particular webgrid column hide

Comment: @PraveenS, customize the columns property and include only the columns you would like to see in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

write down column index in `eq()` and it will work
put this in `document.ready()` function

```
$('.grid table thead tr th:eq(8)').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to hide column with its header Value:
`WebGrid`

```
grid.Column(null,null, format: @<input type="hidden" name="IDHidden" value="@item.IDHidden"/>),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to hide the header but still show the column of data just make the header a single blank space:

```
 grid.Column("Address2", header: " ", style: "cols", canSort: true)
```